# sama5 clock and debug issue

Tags: arm, cortex, j-link

I have designed a board that uses the [ATSAMA5D225C-D1M](https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/ATSAMA5D225C-D1M) (Cortex A5).  I have mostly copied the schematic from the ATSAMA5D27-SOM1.

I am using a J-LINK PRO adapter.

I am using the atmel software framework and GCC to test my new board.

I can single step the debugger until I get to pmc_switch_mck_to_slck()

```
void pmc_switch_mck_to_slck(void)
{
    /* Select Slow Clock as input clock for PCK and MCK */
    PMC->PMC_MCKR = (PMC->PMC_MCKR & ~PMC_MCKR_CSS_Msk) | PMC_MCKR_CSS_SLOW_CLK;
    while (!(PMC->PMC_SR & PMC_SR_MCKRDY));

    _pmc_mck = 0;
}
```

after which the debugger tells me

```
pmc_switch_mck_to_slck () at ../../drivers/peripherals/pmc.c:973
973             PMC->PMC_MCKR = (PMC->PMC_MCKR & ~PMC_MCKR_CSS_Msk) | PMC_MCKR_CSS_SLOW_CLK;
(gdb)
0xdeadbeee in ?? ()
(gdb) s
Cannot find bounds of current function
```

So what is the meaning of all registers returning 0xdeadbeee or 0xdeadbeef?  Am I missing some trap definition?

What types of causes should I look for on the clock switching issue?  Debugger setting or hardware issue?

Comment: That's almost certainly a fault address.  Didn't you already ask about this overall problem recently?

Comment: No, the question was about understanding arm, it was too general and was closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is/was caused by a non working main crystal oscillator.